# Consume Rest service from Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have consume rest service from xamarin form.But my listview not shown that.It shown lots of empty rows only.

### Rest Service Response

```
[
   {
      "prodName":"abc",
      "qty":142.0,
      "price":110.0
   },
   {
      "prodName":"efg",
      "qty":20.0,
      "price":900.0
   }
]
```

### My .xaml file

```
<ListView x:Name="ProductsListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label Text="{Binding prodName}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding price}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

### xaml.cs file

```
private async void GetProducts()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://myUrl/Api/Values");
    var products = response;
    ProductsListView.ItemsSource = products;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how that works. What you are doing now is downloading the JSON as a raw string value and put that in the `ListView`.

You will have to deserialise the downloaded string into a .NET object.

Define a model like this:

```
public class ApiModel
{
    [JsonProperty("prodName")]
    public string prodName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qty")]
    public long qty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public long price { get; set; }
}
```

And get your results like this:

```
private async void GetProducts()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://myUrl/Api/Values");
    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiModel[]>(response);
    ProductsListView.ItemsSource = products;
}
```

Your result JSON string will now be converted to an array of `ApiModel` and the `ListView` can read properties from that.

If you haven't done so already, install JSON.NET and import the right usings (probabably `using Newtonsoft.Json;` and/or `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;`).

You might want to read up on this stuff, for more information look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are getting back a json results, and trying to push it in to a listView ItemSource. Instead use [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert your json to products first

**Given**

```
public class Product
{
    public string prodName { get; set; }
    public double qty { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

**Example**

```
private async void GetProducts()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://myUrl/Api/Values");
    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response);
    ProductsListView.ItemsSource = products;
}
```